# Rendering django cms page as json

Tags: python, json, django, django-cms

I have a django CMS page, I want the rendered html to be made into a json object(dump the CMS html into JSON), is this possible? I'd like it to look something like this:

[image]

How would I go about this?

So after some digging , this is what I managed.

CMS has a views.py which has a function "details(request, slug)"
I used this method to render the required page, by passing the slug of the page I need rendered , got the response and put it into a JSON object and returned this.

```
from cms.views import details

 def index(request, topic):

if topic == 'home':
    template = details(request, '')
else:
    template = details(request, topic)

content = ''
if hasattr(template, 'render'):
    # TemplateResponse must call render() before we can get the content
    content = template.render().content
else:
    # HttpResponse does not have a render() method
    content = template.content

# Send JSON response
return JsonResponse({ 
    'createdAt': datetime.datetime.now(),
    'content': content 
})
```

Any better way of doing the same?

Comment: do you want to dump your HTML code into JSON? how do you imagine such output?

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/FHQ87M0)

Something like this

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be fairly easy. Instead of returning the rendered output from the template, put it in a dictionary. Then just `from json import dumps` or `dump` and [`dump(dictionary)` / `dumps(dictionary)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) depending on your purpose. `dumps` gives you a string. `dump` gives you something fancier.

Comment: But wouldn't that be for just one plugin?
My page has several plugins , all these plugins render their own templates, and form a page . I need this whole page(consisting of all the html from all plugins) as a json object . If it helps please check the link I've added

[link](http://imgur.com/FHQ87M0)

Comment: IIRC, your view method in Django returns something when it is called. So when someone gets a page, your program does something and then it returns something. Regardless of how many plugins you have, what it returns is the HTML I believe, so instead of returning it, just store it into a variable.

Or... at least give that a go before you get more fancy.

Comment: *"something fancier"* - `dump` just writes the exact same string representation to a file (or file-like object).